# Is it possible to declare variables procedurally using Rust macros?

Tags: macros, rust

Basically, there are two parts to this question:

1. Can you pass an unknown identifier to a macro in [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/)?
2. Can you combine strings to generate new variable names in a Rust macro?

For example, something like:

```rust
macro_rules! expand(
  ($x:ident) => (
    let mut x_$x = 0;
  )
)
```

Calling expand!(hi) obvious fails because hi is an unknown identifier; but can you somehow do this?

ie. The equivalent in C of something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define FN(Name, base) \
  int x1_##Name = 0 + base; \
  int x2_##Name = 2 + base; \
  int x3_##Name = 4 + base; \
  int x4_##Name = 8 + base; \
  int x5_##Name = 16 + base;

int main() {
  FN(hello, 10)
  printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", x1_hello, x2_hello, x3_hello, x4_hello, x5_hello);
  return 0;
}
```

Why you say, what a terrible idea. Why would you ever want to do that?

I'm glad you asked!

Consider this rust block:

```rust
{
   let marker = 0;
   let borrowed = borrow_with_block_lifetime(data, &marker); 
   unsafe {
      perform_ffi_call(borrowed);
   }
}
```

You now have a borrowed value with an explicitly bounded lifetime (marker) that isn't using a structure lifetime, but that we can guarantee exists for the entire scope of the ffi call; at the same time we don't run into obscure errors where a `*` is de-referenced unsafely inside an unsafe block and so the compiler doesn't catch it as an error, despite the error being made *inside a safe block*.

(see also [Why are all my pointers pointing to the same place with to_c_str() in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053398/why-are-all-my-pointers-pointing-to-the-same-place-with-to-c-str-in-rust))

The use a macro that can declare temporary variables for this purpose would considerably ease the troubles I have fighting with the compiler. That's why I want to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes however this is only available as a nightly-only experimental API which may be removed.

You can pass arbitrary identifier into a macro and yes, you can concatenate identifiers into a new identifier using [`concat_idents!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html) macro:

```rust
#![feature(concat_idents)]

macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => ({
        let z = concat_idents!(hello_, $x);
        z();
    })
}

fn hello_world() {  }

fn main() {
    test!(world);
}
```

However, as far as I know, because `concat_idents!()` itself is a macro, you can't use this concatenated identifier *everywhere* you could use plain identifier, only in certain places like in example above, and this, in my opinion, is a HUGE drawback. Just yesterday I tried to write a macro which could remove a lot of boilerplate in my code, but eventually I was not able to do it because macros do not support arbitrary placement of concatenated identifiers.

BTW, if I understand your idea correctly, you don't really need concatenating identifiers to obtain unique names. Rust macros, contrary to the C ones, are [hygienic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro). This means that all names of local variables introduced inside a macro won't leak to the scope where this macro is called. For example, you could assume that this code would work:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($body:expr) => ({ let x = 10; $body })
}

fn main() {
    let y = test!(x + 10);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

That is, we create a variable `x` and put an expression after its declaration. It is then natural to think that `x` in `test!(x + 10)` refers to that variable declared by the macro, and everything should be fine, but in fact this code won't compile:

```
main3.rs:8:19: 8:20 error: unresolved name `x`.
main3.rs:8     let y = test!(x + 10);
                             ^
main3.rs:3:1: 5:2 note: in expansion of test!
main3.rs:8:13: 8:27 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So if all you need is uniqueness of locals, then you can safely do nothing and use any names you want, they will be unique automatically. This is [explained](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html#hygiene) in macro tutorial, though I find the example there somewhat confusing.

Comment: concat_idents might me removed, it was already feature-gated [#13295](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/13295) and [#13294](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/13294)

Comment: We really need this feature akin to ## in C.  I constantly have to write macros where users give me two names because string concat is so limited.

Comment: The claim that Rust macro variables can't leak isn't fair though, because Rust macro declaration always requires a wrapping `{}` (or other delimiters). Using the same syntax in C, you would still not leak symbols.

Comment: @SOFe note that the above example would work in C: https://onlinegdb.com/SkhTzjQ-r . The idea is, in C you can access variables defined by the macro quite easily as long as you know the macro definition. In Rust you cannot, and whether there are any blocks or not is not really relevant.

Comment: Is there any way to generate a lot of functions like `handler_0, handler_1, handler_2, ...`, with an `literal` after the underscore?

Answer (score 12):

There is also https://github.com/dtolnay/paste, which works well in cases where `concat_idents` is underpowered or in cases where you can't target the nightly compiler.

```rust
macro_rules! foo_macro {
    ( $( $name:ident ),+ ) => {
        paste! {
            #[test]
            fn [<test_ $name>]() {
                assert! false
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: In case it's not clear, `[<test_ $name>]` is where the concatenation is happening. The result will be a function whose name is the concatenation of `test_` and `$name`. Also, it might be a good idea to add an example of how to invoke this macro and what the result would look like.

Answer (score 5):

In cases where `concat_idents` doesn't work (which is most cases I'd like to use it) changing the problem from concatenated identifiers to using namespaces does work.

That is, instead of the non-working code:

```
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => ({
        struct concat_idents!(hello_, $x) {}
        enum contact_idents!(hello_, $x) {}
    })
}
```

The user can name the namespace, and then have preset names as shown below:

```
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => ({
        mod $x {
            struct HelloStruct {}
            enum HelloEnum {}
        }
    })
}
```

Now you have a name based on the macro's argument. This technique is only helpful in specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect your identifiers into a struct if you don't want to use nightly and external crates and your identifiers are types.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn print_f<T: Debug>(v: &T){
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

macro_rules! print_all {
    ($($name:ident),+) => {
        struct Values{
            $($name: $name),+
        }
        let values = Values{
            $(
                $name: $name::default()
            ),+
        };
        $(
            print_f(&values.$name);
        )+
    };
}

fn main(){
    print_all!(String, i32, usize);
}
```

This code prints

```
""
0
0
```

If you fear that `Value` will conflict with some type name, you can use some long UUID as part of the name:

```rust
struct Values_110cf51d7a694c808e6fe79bf1485d5b{
   $($name:$name),+
}
```