# Is it possible for a macro to turn an identifier lowercase?

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible to generate a symbol or identifier in a Rust macro
from a string? Or to perform string-like operations on a identifier?

I wanted to generate a method given a symbol, but need to downcase it to
obtain the method name.

```
get!(B);

// should expand to

fn b() -> B {
    // method body
}
```

It's easy to get close...

```
macro_rules! get {
    ($kind:ident, $method:ident)
        =>
    {
        fn $method() -> $kind {
           // method body
        }
    }
}

get!(B, b)
```

But dissatisfying.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23061702/1233251 https://stackoverflow.com/q/27415011/1233251

Comment: I run into this language limitation all the time.  It'd make the code so much more pleasant to have this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a macro that can perform this sort of string manipulation on identifiers.

It is possible to create such a macro in the compiler, but it doesn't seem to be a popular need; today only the experimental [`concat_idents!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/macro.concat_idents.html) comes anything close to this (i.e. string-like operations for identifiers).

Your workaround is currently the only available solution.

Comment: Yeah, I had found `concat_idents!`, but it's not the right thing. Thanks anyway, good to know that it's not worth searching for.

Comment: Also, `concat_idents!` has a lot of downsides which such a macro probably would have as well.

Comment: dtolnay's paste crate is a good way to do this now: https://crates.io/crates/paste

Answer (score 16):

I just wrote a procedural macro ([casey](https://crates.io/crates/casey)) to do this.

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene)]

use casey::lower;

lower!(B); // would render as `b`
```

### Update

`proc_macro_hygiene` is stable as of rust 1.45.0, so no longer requires nightly.

Comment: Stuff like this puts a big big smile on my face. Thanks to your good work, one of my business logic source files went from 2k+ lines to something like 400 . Can you tell how happy I am?

Answer (score 9):

The previous answers are all correct; standard declarative macros can't do this, and you can drop to procedural macros instead. However, a simpler alternative to procedural macros (especially if, like myself, that's an area of the language you haven't delved into yet) is dtolnay's [paste crate](https://crates.io/crates/paste).

An example from those docs:

```
use paste::paste;

paste! {
    // Defines a const called `QRST`.
    const [<Q R S T>]: &str = "success!";
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        paste! { [<Q R S T>].len() },
        8,
    );
}
```

Case conversion is also supported, e.g. `[<ld_ $reg:lower _expr>]`