# How can I generate templated const declarations?

Tags: rust

I was sitting typing a ton of repetitive code and thought - I should write a macro to do this. Then I realized that what I need cannot be done with the type of macro that I know how to write.

Here is what I need (it's describing the location of bits in a u16):

```
const XXX_OFF: u16 = n;
const XXX: Word = 1 << XXX_OFF;
```

e.g.

```
const RTS_OFF: u16 = 0;
const RTS: Word = 1 << RTS_OFF;

const CTS_OFF: u16 = 3;
const CTS: Word = 1 << CTS_OFF;

// ...
```

declaring the offset and generating a bitmask for each named bit in a `u16`.

As you can see the only things that change are `XXX` and `n`. Is there anyway I could automate this? It would be trivial in C. I wonder if there is some form of template driven proc macro out there. Or if there is another way of achieving the same thing. Maybe I have to go learn how to write proc macros.

Comment: If you use a declarative macro in Rust, you need to parametrize it with `n`, `XXX` _and_ `XXX_OFF`, since there is no way to dynamically create identifiers in a delcarative macro.

Comment: @SvenMarnach even then its not doable, a declarative macro cannot generate new items in its callers namespace -> hygiene

Comment: @pm100 Sure you can. That's not how macro hygiene works in Rust. Simply try it, and you'll see it works.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `_OFF` constants aren't really needed. You can use `XXX.trailing_zeros()` instead. The `trailing_zeros()` function is `const`, so this will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - i actually built my solution using your suggestions a) you can do it just not generate new names b) use trailing_zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather dirty solution (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48272795/8564999) answer) would be to create a module with the name of e.g. `RTS` and put a public constant `OFF` in it, so you can access it as `RTS::OFF`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2008810fa347be5b1bbb771523bd4127)

```
macro_rules! define_word {
    ($name:ident, $bit:expr) => {
        mod $name {
            pub const OFF: u16 = $bit;
        }
        const $name: Word = 1 << $bit;
    };

}

define_word!(RTS, 0);
define_word!(CTS, 3);

fn main() {
    println!("{} {}", RTS::OFF, RTS);
    println!("{} {}", CTS::OFF, CTS);
}
```

Comment: thats pretty good. Feels to me like there is a space for a proc macro that can take a code template and fill in the blanks. As a generic tool

Answer (score 2):

The [`paste`](https://crates.io/crates/paste) crate is exactly the "code template" tool you're looking for. As of writing, 1.0.0 isn't available on the playground, so I'm using 0.1.18:

```
extern crate paste; // 0.1.18
type Word = u16;

macro_rules! bitfield_with_offset {
    ($name:ident, $bit:expr) => {
        paste::item! {
        const [<$name _OFF>]: u16 = $bit;
        }
        const $name:  Word = 1 << $bit;
    }
}

bitfield_with_offset!(ASD, 5);

fn main() {
    println!("{}, {}", ASD_OFF, ASD);
}
```

This will output:

```
5, 32
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=076efee87ecc731fe563bca73e31d1db)

It seems 1.0.0 removes the `item!` macro for a more flexible generic `paste!` macro, so your solution may look a little different.